# Access nested query values - Apex repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've below query

```
SItems=[SELECT id, name, (SELECT id,Status__c FROM VObject__r) FROM SOObject__c limit 12 ];
```

And VF page as below;

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!SItems}" var="SOItem" >
  <tr>
     <td>{!SOItem.name}</td>
     <td>How to access VObjects status here</td>
 </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<apex:repeat value="{!SItems}" var="SOItem">
   <tr>
       <td>{!SOItem.name}</td>
           <apex:repeat value="{!SOItem.VObject__r}" var="Vnested" >
                <td>You access</td>
           </apex:repeat>
  </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

or: if you don't want to use nested repeat structure
 `<apex:inputField value="{!SOItem.VObject__r[0]}"/>` 
But i wouldn't recommend this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code: But the child record will be displayed only the first 1. If you have multiple child records it will not display more than the 0th index.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!SItems}" var="SOItem" >
    <tr>
      <td>{!SOItem.name}</td>
      <td>{!SOItem.VObject__r[0].Status__c}</td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Mark this answer if you find this working correctly.

Comment: I need to use apex: repeat only. And also for following  td tag directly i need to put first row of inner query, without having another var="soitem1"
   <td>How to access VObjects status here</td>

Comment: So if there are two child records associated with a parent you want to display the 1st child records only right?

Comment: Please add the code properly with your objects i just tried this code for Account and Contacts so it is working correctly. Thanks